# Checking for expiring membership

Tags: mysql, node.js, timedelta

In my nodejs server I have 2 types of memberships (Free, Paid). 
Paid Membership lasts exactly 31 days from the day it's been bought.

When a member buys such a membership I (server-side) `UPDATE` my database (MySQL) in a field `paid_expires` which accepts a `TIMESTAMP` input with the current date plus 31 days.

If my server has X paying members who purchased their memberships on different dates, what is an efficient way of informing everyone 3 hours beforehand that their membership expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of elements to address for this so I'll go through them one by one

First of all you'll want to have some function that runs on an interval. This can be handled by a [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```js
setInterval(() => {
  /**
  * perform the magic here or call another function.
  * Note that if you're working with classes you cannot reference "this"
  * here without first setting it before the interval to a const
  * for example with "const that = this;"
  */
}, 60000); // runs every minute
```

Next to address is the callback function executed by the interval, which is where all the magic happens. You will first want to query your database for all members who have a paid membership. i.e. if that is determines by whether the `paid_expires` column is `NOT NULL` then it would be something such as `SELECT memberId, paid_expires FROM member WHERE paid_expires IS NOT NULL`.
The following step depends on how your mysql database driver returns the rows but I'll assume it is an array of objects. You now have an array of all paying users and their expiry dates.

Assumed output of SQL query

```
let members = [
  {
    memberId: "b6c4aeb1-6a23-477c-856a-d5f898153b62",
    paid_expires: "2018-03-12T14:00:00"
  },
  {
    memberId: "afc89eee-ef5e-4fbf-8451-aeac5620abe6",
    paid_expires: "2018-03-12T16:30:00"
  }
];
```

The final step is to loop through this array of objects and calculate whether they are 3 hours or less from expiration. For this you will want to use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com)'s `add`,`diff` and `duration` functions. You can use `add` to add 31 days to the value from the database and then you can use the combination of `duration` and `diff` to determine if the notification has to be send

Example of the last part would be

```
const expiryDate = moment(sqlrow.paid_expires).add(31, 'd');
const timeout = moment.duration(expiryDate.diff());

if (timeout.asHours() <= 3) {
  // send notification
}
```

[Here is a runkit notebook showing this code in action](https://runkit.com/favna/so-checking-for-expiring-membership)

Comment: Thank you! As per functionality it seems great, but is a function that runs every minute for e.g. 2500 users efficient? Not judging of course I am just curious!

Comment: The interval of 1 minute was merely meant as an example. I was thinking about making a note of that but decided against it as I wasn't sure how many members you were having to deal with. That said, this is the only way to run some function multiple times when you exclusively use JavaScript. 

There's 2 options to cover this issue
1. Further research, looking into how long a loop of the function takes and adjust the interval time accordingly. 
2. What I would do personally, set it to 5-10 minutes. Should be plenty for notifications that start at 3 hours.

Comment: I am going with option number 2! Thanks!